# Can't install selenium.webdriver.common.keys packages on python 2.7?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, package, python-import

I have pip 9.0.1 and selenium 3.3.1 when a make `pip install keys` or try `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys` from pycharm prompts this  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keys (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for keys`

Im using pycharm last version. I search throw all the web but im newbie some sayed that is a network problem. Others that it's path environment are bad. But how im suposed to know all that the are millions of path enviroment i don't wanna screw up all i have made a project that i want to work in the future. I have been messing around with the terminal searching for archive's permission.. I wish i could give you more info about the problem but i search a lot and there isnt a quite good answer to begin to start solve the problem ..

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

It's included in the selenium package. You're just trying to import it wrong, Keys is capitalized.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: Thank you im little embarrassing